# Não consegue capturar o erro no sql

Tags: mysql, delphi

```
try
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tdcupant');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE numcupom = :co2 AND ccf = :cc3 AND dtcompra = :dtc4 AND impcaixa = :ip5');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('co2').AsString := copy(lTemp,53,6);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('cc3').AsString := copy(lTemp,47,6);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ip5').AsString := copy(lTemp,4,20);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtc4').AsDate := StrToDate(dtcompratxt);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;
     except
       on e: Exception do
       begin
       ercp := e.Message;
       StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Erro ao encontrar registros! ' + ercp;
     end;
```

Acredito que esta certo. Porém ele fica indicando o erro do próprio `sql`.
Bom, o erro que dá é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ser preciso, ele apenas precisa capturar uma exceção para caso nenhum dos registros que comparei nos parâmetros sejam encontrados no banco de dados.

Comment: Qual erro? testou a consulta direto no banco?

Comment: @perdeu Sim, a consulta apresentada ai, é que precisa de ter os registros cadastrados no banco para igualar com os parâmetros, porém, obviamente não é todo arquivo .txt que existe os registros corretos que está no banco de dados, o erro é de `Sql Sintaxe`, que é quando não encontra nenhum registro, depois que percorre todo o banco e o arquivo txt.

Comment: @perdeu, mas é exatamente isso que estou fazendo, provocando erro selecionando um arquivo errado, para eu tratar ele, mas não está tratando.

Comment: @RamonRuan Exception ao realizar o open não significa que não encountou registros. Um erro de sintaxe é quando sua query está escrita errada. Transcreva o erro para que fique mais fácil podermos ajudar. E se você tratar `on e: Exception`significa todo tipo de exceção e portanto nunca irá cair no seu `else`. Se o que você quer é lançar uma exceção se não encontrar registros, aí é outra coisa

Comment: @Caputo, segue logo em cima a imagem do erro. O else, foi só um pequeno teste, como estou reaprendendo a linguagem, tem muita coisa que perdi e falta aprender. haha

Comment: Não será a falta de um espaço entre `SELECT * FROM tdcupant` e `WHERE...`?

Comment: @JorgeB. acredito que não, pois eles estão em linhas diferentes quando são adicionadas. Mas só para teste, fiz, mas msm assim aparece.

Comment: Experimenta por um espaço antes de `WHERE`. Costuma ser a maior parte dos meu problemas com SQL.

Comment: Antes do `DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open` dá um `Showmessage(DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Text)` e diz o que aparece, por favor.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca `SELECT * FROM tdcupant WHERE numcupom = :co2 AND ccf = :cc3 AND dtcompra = :dtc4 AND impcaixa = :ip5`, esta mensagem, com `sql`.

Comment: Ia postar como comentário, mas ficou grande d+, então foi como resposta. Se não funcionar edito posteriormente.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, eu estava olhando meu código, e debugguei em outro canto, pus um ponto para cada começo de while e if existente naquele procedimento, e achei uma linha aonde, "se não encontrasse nenhum registro ele iria dar um  valor=''..." sql não aceita nada no campo e sim um 0. Vou postar a resposta agora mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugguei o código mais uma vez e encontrei

```
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Close;
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tabc460 LIMIT 0, '+valor);
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Open;
```

Esse `valor`, é um incremento de caso encontre registros divergentes. Mas, pensem assim, se não encontra nenhum registro, não vai incrementar nenhum valor né?

Bom, está aí, eu pensei que só era naquele momento ali,  por que estava percorrendo todo o banco de dados, daí deu certo.

```
if (valor = '') then
  begin
    valor := IntToStr(0);
  end;
```

Fiz apenas esse tratamento, pra caso não encontra `nada`, encontre `0`;

Comment: Resolveste o problema? Não percebi como...

Comment: @JorgeB. Aquele código lá em cima é apenas para SELEÇÃO e COMPARAÇÃO, esse mesmo código entra em um loop para identificar divergências entre os campos do DB e campos do ARQUIVO .txt, então como disse em cima, o incremento `valor`, será usado para caso haja divergências entre os campos, e esse codigo nesta resposta corresponde à SELEÇÃO DOS ÚLTIMOS DADOS INSERIDOS NO BD, que no caso, são as divergências.

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço seu componente de acesso a dados, porém, acho que vale tentar:

Substitua

```pascal
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tdcupant');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE numcupom = :co2 AND ccf = :cc3 AND dtcompra = :dtc4 AND impcaixa = :ip5');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('co2').AsString := copy(lTemp,53,6);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('cc3').AsString := copy(lTemp,47,6);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ip5').AsString := copy(lTemp,4,20);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtc4').AsDate := StrToDate(dtcompratxt);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;
```

Por:

```
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Text := Format('SELECT * FROM tdcupant WHERE numcupom = %s AND ccf = %s AND dtcompra = %s AND impcaixa = %s', [copy(lTemp,53,6),copy(lTemp,47,6),copy(lTemp,4,20),FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd',StrToDate(dtcompratxt))]);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;
```

Comment: testei o seu jeito e funcionou tambem, mas continuou o erro, então fiz o que postei e deu certo tambem. Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Então cara, esse erro é por erro de SINTAXE no comando SQL, debuga ele e veja todos os valores das variáveis que está utilizando para compor o comando, feito isso pegue o conteúdo e rode o comando direto no Banco de dados com os valores no lugar das variáveis.

Ficará muito mais fácil de você encontrar o erro no comando dessa forma.

Também verifique aquele parâmetro "IP5", pois não vi ele sendo utilizado em nenhuma parte do comando.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: esta sendo usado sim, olha la, na `SELEÇÃO` e nos `PARAMETROS`.